# How to get rows from a SQL table just ignoring the rows which have duplicate values in one particular column

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

I know that if I want to have distict values in case of duplicates, I can use DISTINCT. But what I want is that if there is a duplicate value in one of the columns, I don't need any row from that .

eg.

| ORDER_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| ORD1 | Aaron |
| ORD2 | BOB |
| ORD3 | Carry |
| ORD1 | Danny |
| ORD2 | Emily |
| ORD2 | Frank |

In this case, I just want the result as:

| ORDER_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| ORD3 | Carry |

Since ORD1 and ORD3 are repeated.

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS(...)`

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i tried this and it worked for me.

```
SELECT Order_Id, MAX(Name) as Name FROM table GROUP BY Order_Id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation with `GROUP BY` and specify a condition on the groups with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Will only work for duplicate values of order_id.

Comment: @stefan, select * is giving an error that I should group by other columns as well. But I want to provide all columns to an outer query from this. something like this:
Star expansion expression references column CORRELATION_ID which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think of is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM tbl GROUP BY name HAVING count(name) > 1) AND order_id NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM tbl GROUP BY order_id HAVING count(order_id) > 1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just group by both columns in a single subquery? Regardless I don't get the impression that name is relevant for this de-dup.

Comment: If I group by both columns, either rows like (ORD1, "Jack") and (ORD2, "Jack") or rows like (ORD1, "Jack") and (ORD1, "Jill") would not be filtered out (depending on which order you group in). And the question reads "But what I want is that if there is a duplicate value in one of the columns I don't need any row from that". It's pretty specific about both columns being relevant there.

Comment: Of course that was a dumb comment about the grouping. But the other point was legit: there's exactly one particular column of relevance, not *any* of one of several.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` is a typical approach:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.order_id = t.order_id and t2.name <> t.name);
```